# How to create rotating wheel control in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, uicontrol

I want to create a rotating widget for iPhone application. Something similar [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit). But in this selected section is at left (0 degrees). It starts populating sections form left (0 degrees). I want selected section at top (90 degrees).

Please note number of sections are odd in my case. So adjusting top section must be properly adjusted at top center.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Sayali

Comment: So, what's the problem? Just add 90 degrees wherever necessary.

Comment: I am not able to figure where to add 90 degrees. Because there is not any property/method to set the starting point

Comment: It's not clear where you're having trouble. What have you tried? How far have you gotten on your own?

Comment: What i want is a rotating control having some odd say 7 segments. User will tap on any 1 which he wants to select. That tapped/selected segment should animate to top-center segment & highlight as selected & get selected segment. I have tried above sample. But in this selected segment is in left. I am not able to make it top center

Comment: Also in above sample code, rotation of control is manual. That is user have to drag circular. I want automated rotation. That is when user taps of any one of the segment, that segment should automatically rotate to top center

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) library for that. It is very customizable.

Or maybe you want to try out the new `UICollectionView`, you can customize its layout as well so that it looks like a wheel.

Comment: iCarousel is not a wheel-like widget. And UICollectionView is available in iOS 6.0. My application's target is iOS 4 onwards

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the source you cite, it explains exactly where it sets the starting point. When filling in first the labels and then the images, it is really irrelevant where you start.

The only difference is the graphic surrounding the wheel with the indicator on the left. Simply rotate that and you are done.

Comment: In function -(void)drawWheel, it does set images & forms segment but by default it adds cloveSegment subview from 0 degress. I did not find any thing to set it to start from 90 degress.

Comment: Just exchange the images. It does not matter in which order you add them, so go with the code template you are using to get them to the desired position.

Comment: I understand this way. But doing this, section at top does not come in center as I have odd number of sections. Its bit tilted towards right & I am not able to make it at perfect top center

Comment: Change `im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize * i)`to `im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize * i +angleSize/2)`.